# This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used on Map

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm new in flutter.

I'm receiving data from a DB server.

```
Map<String, double> dataMap = {};
var queryService = client.getQueryService();

var records = await queryService.query(query);
await records.forEach((record) {

  DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
  String formatedDate = dateFormat.format(DateTime.parse('${record['_time']}')); //Converting DateTime object to String

  dataList.add('$formatedDate : ${record['_value']}');
  dataMap[formatedDate] = double.parse('${record['_value']}');
});
print(dataMap);
client.close();
```

So I need to pass the dataMap data to a function:

```
dataMap.forEach((key, value) {
                        ChartData (key, value);
                      })
```

But I'm receiving the 'void' error... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[`Iterable.forEach`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Iterable/forEach.html) does not return anything.  It makes no sense to `await` its result. [`Map.forEach`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Map/forEach.html) similarly does not return anything, so you cannot pass its result as an argument to a function.  Additionally, your callback does not do anything; `ChartData(key, value)` by itself constructs a `ChartData` object but then discards it.

If you want to convert `dataMap` to a `List<ChartData>`, you need to iterate over `dataMap` and build a `List`:

```dart
var chartDataList = dataMap.entries.map(
  (keyValue) => ChartData(keyValue.key, keyValue.value),
).toList();
```

or use collection-`for`:

```dart
var chartDataList = [
  for (var keyValue in dataMap.entries)
    ChartData(keyValue.key, keyValue.value),
];
```

Comment: Got it, thanks for the explanation! The ChartData is used inside a chart function, it's working correct.